# Some notes on $D_n, S_n$ and $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/repth/sol2.pdf

In these solutions it refers to See "Some notes on $D_n, S_n$ and $A_n$". Does anyone know where these notes can be found? They sound extremely useful.

EDIT: Does anyone know of any resources like this that give many examples of how to find conjugacy classes, normal subgroups, ismorphisms between groups and subgroup for the above groups?

Comment: have you tried deleting bits of the web address??

Comment: @Paul Yes. They are not on the page http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/repth/ either